# How to set a function to the max value in boxplot highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, boxplot

I am using Angular with highcharts boxplot API.
I know I could set the max value of y-axis in the chart config, something like this.

```
max: 100, 
tickInterval: 10.
```

But now I need to change the max value by the return value.
For example, if the maximum return value is around 60%, then I should set the max to 60.

```
max:60, 
tickInterval: 10.
```

Is there any way to add some method/function to fit the maximum return value?
For example:

```
max: funticon(){ xxxxx; return A},
tickInterval: 10
```

The above function is a method by myself to check the API maximum value.
After checking then return to the chart config to set the max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using chart.events.load you will be able to update and set these values for yAxis.max:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-wtoktb

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function() {
      const chart = this;
      chart.update({
        yAxis: {
          max: (chart.yAxis[0] as any).dataMax
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi very appreciated for the help.  It works for dynamically changing the max value of the Y axis. But there comes out another issue, the y axis title which I assigned was all set to "Value" instead of the text I assign. Is there any other workaround ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. When it comes to this value, you mean yAxis.title.text? If so, you can set it freely: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.title.text